# Undefined Reference, DisparityBilateralFilter in OpenCV using CUDA

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm a beginner with OpenCV and CUDA so sorry, if this Question is trivial.
I've installed CUDA 9.0 with, OpenCV 3.3.1 and I'm using Qt 5.

I try to filter a disparity map with cuda::DisparityBilaterFilter. Unfortunately It's not working.

Code Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/ximgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/cudastereo.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    int nDisp = 64;
    int radius = 3;
    int iters = 1;
    Ptr<cuda::DisparityBilateralFilter>  pCudaBilFilter = cuda::createDisparityBilateralFilter(nDisp, radius, iters);

//    pCudaBilFilter->apply(DispMapInp, LeftImages, filteredDispMap);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting en error:

```
error: undefined reference to `cv::cuda::createDisparityBilateralFilter(int, int, int)'
```

Other OpenCV Code (like StereoMatching) is working fine. What am I missing? I'm sure it's a stupid mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You said that "other OpenCV Code is working fine" - I assume you checked any other function in `cv::cuda` namespace? Because if not maybe something is off with your cuda configuration. By the way your example compiles for me (I only changed includes to `<opencv2/opencv.hpp>` only), OCV3.3.0, CUDA 8.0, VS15

Answer (score 1):

Solved it myself now. Forgot to add the library -lopencv_cudastereo to my .pro file.